# JSON Schema - how to get the same result from different data types

Tags: json, jsonschema, jsonparser

I have stumbled here upon several answers regarding handling multiple types of data in JSON, but none of them helps me in my concrete case. I am a beginner in JSON, so any help is highly appreciated.

Namely, I can get the same data from HTTP request as an object in these two variations:

First case:

```
"cac:PayeeFinancialAccount": {
    "cbc:ID": {
        "@schemeID": "IBAN",
        "#text": "220-115524-04"
    }
```

Second case:

```
    "cac:PayeeFinancialAccount": {
    "cbc:ID": "220-115524-04"
    }
```

Is there a way to get the same form of result from parsing this JSON in any of those cases, a plain string I can grab later in my app, just "220-115524-04" that I can call via like `['cac:PayeeFinancialAccount']?['cbc:ID']` (ignoring other properties)?

Thanks everybody in advance.

I have tried employing "oneOf" from some other answers here, with some success, but couldn't manage to get the same output for both cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without seeing your JSON Schema, it's hard to determine what you have tried or how the schema was written.

This should work to validate both of your instances.

- `oneOf` constrains `cbc:ID` to either an object with the properties defined or a string.

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "cac:PayeeFinancialAccount": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "cbc:ID": {
          "oneOf": [
            {
              "type": "object",
              "additionalProperties": false,
              "properties": {
                "@schemeID": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "#text": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "type": "string"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Jeremy Fiel, this solves my problem, but partially. Namely, I need to, whatever the variance is, get only [cbc:ID] as string as the result of parsing - in first case its value is [cbc:ID][#text], and in another one it is just [cbc:ID].

Comment: I'm not sure using JSON Schema is the right solution.  This is only used for validating the instance of data to be either `object` or `string`.  It cant help with extracting the values as a result of parsing